# Ejecución de código JS EN GENEXUS X EVO3

Tags: javascript, genexus

Quisiera saber si me puedes ayudar. Trabajo con GX X EVO3.
En el siguiente código:

```
Event 'imprimirReporte'
   tb1.caption = "[script]alert('imprimir...')[/script]" // usé [] x <>
   printReporte() // procedure reporte GX
EndEvent
//tb1 es un texto block HTML en defino el script js.
//Usé [] porque si escribo <> no sale la palabra script. Mil disculpas
```

**Se ejectua primero el printReporte()**

> ¿Cómo logro que se ejecuten esas dos líneas en el órden en que están? Es decir primero que se ejecute el script js.
>   Gracias por tu tiempo! Saludos

Comment: Porque no usas jsevent y se lo asocias al control q llama al reporte en el evento start.?

Comment: Usa outsystems, genexus va de salida

Comment: Aprecio tu comentario, pero por temas laborales, no es decisión mía. Gracias.

Comment: @Icors: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Con la sugerencia de @Icors, encontré la solución y funciona muy bien.

Insertar un objeto imagen y asociarle el código JS, mediante JSEvent.

```
Event Start

   tb1.caption="funcionJS(){ // aqui el codigo javascript....;     return true; } "

   //importante la línea: return true para que luego ejecute imprimirReporte

   // tb1 es un textblock HTML.

    imgAceptar.JSEvent("onclick", "funcionJS()" )



EndEvent



Event 'imprimirReporte' // eventoGx definido en propiedad "on click event" de imgAceptar

    printReporte()

EndEvent
```

Saludos y gracias por el interés..